# Is this java functional version of the double checked lock safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, optimization, concurrency, locking

I'm trying to implement a reusable functional-like version of the double checked lock (DCL) pattern in Java.

Indeed, there are many known problems with the DCL pattern in Java, like those [ones](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/LCK10-J.+Use+a+correct+form+of+the+double-checked+locking+idiom). So I'm trying to check if the solution I develop has any flaws.

Here is the DCL executor code:

```java
public class DoubleCheckedLockExecutor {

    public <T> T getOrCreate(Supplier<T> supplier, Supplier<T> builder, Consumer<T> consumer, Predicate<T> build) {

        if (build.test(supplier.get())) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (build.test(supplier.get())) {
                    consumer.accept(builder.get());
                }
            }
        }
        return supplier.get();
    }
}
```

And here a Singleton class that uses it:

```java
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton instance = null;
    private static final AtomicInteger instanceCount = new AtomicInteger();
    private static final DoubleCheckedLockExecutor dclExec = new DoubleCheckedLockExecutor();

    private Singleton() {
        instanceCount.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return dclExec.getOrCreate(() -> instance, Singleton::new, s -> instance = s, s -> s == null);
    }

    public static int getInstanceCount() {
        return instanceCount.get();
    }
}
```

And finally some test code:

```java
@Test
public final void testGetOrCreate() {
    int calls = 1000;
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < calls; i++) {
            executor.execute(() -> Singleton.getInstance());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
    }
    assertEquals(1, Singleton.getInstanceCount());
}
```

All tests and analysis I did showed no problems (duplicated instances, for example). But multi-thread and concurrency test is not such easy task for me. So could you guys help me out with this? Could I say this implementation is thread safe and produce the expected results?

Comment: Ran some jcstress tests on it, seems like it works.

Comment: I want to say no. I believe this falls prey to the same issues as the normal DCL solutions where the static field `instance` should be volatile to alleviate data-race issues. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840773/need-of-volatile-keyword-in-case-of-dcl) for the standard `volatile` approach. What I'm unsure of is if the use of the supplier would return a fully initialized object, or fall prey to the same issues as the non-wrapped constructor call (i.e because of use of method-reference).

Comment: I think it depends entirely upon what your supplier and predicate looks like. In your example, it doesn't seem like there is any happens-before relation between the reads and writes to `instance` that would prevent a data race. Although, I wonder if you change your code such that your predicate checks `instanceCount` and if you make sure to initialize all your fields in the singleton before calling `instanceCount.incrementAndGet()` if that would be enough.